# How to create 3 boxes containing, each containing an image and some text?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to position one heading on top of each box HTML https://codepen.io/supertata/pen/RwNZoGX.

I've tried "float" and "flex" and haven't succeeded. Can anyone recommended a way to achieve that?

It is to include in my FreecodeCamp project 2, "Create a product landing page".
Thanks for your help.

```
<div class=headings>
  <h2 id="firstheading" class="convertableheading">Mini Convertable</h2>
  <h2 id="secondheading" class="regularheading">Regular Mini</h2>
  <h2 id=thirdheading class=countryheading>Countryman Mini</h2>
</div>


<div class="boxes" class="container">
  <a href="#"><img id="convertiblemini" class="box1" href="#" src="https://vcache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/AHRUND1806DT-S-/800/f" alt="convertible mini cooper"></a>
</div>


<div class=container>
   <a href="#"><img id="countrymanmini" class="box2" class="miniphotobox"  src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staticeu.izmocars.com/toolkit/commonassets/2018/18mini/18minicountrymans5ha2e/18minicountrymans5ha2e_animations/colorpix/fr/640x480/mini_18countrymans5ha2e_thundergreymetallise.jpg"></a>
</div>


<div class=container>
  <a href="#"><img id="regularmini" class="box3" class="miniphotobox" src="https://picolio.auto123.com/15photo/mini/2015-mini-cooper-s_1.png"</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a lot of errors. Here is an example using flex with minimum code,

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.col img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="col">
    <h2>Mini Convertable</h2>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://vcache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/AHRUND1806DT-S-/800/f" alt="Mini Convertable" />
      </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Regular Mini</h2>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staticeu.izmocars.com/toolkit/commonassets/2018/18mini/18minicountrymans5ha2e/18minicountrymans5ha2e_animations/colorpix/fr/640x480/mini_18countrymans5ha2e_thundergreymetallise.jpg" alt="Regular Mini" />
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Countryman Mini</h2>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://picolio.auto123.com/15photo/mini/2015-mini-cooper-s_1.png" alt="Countryman Mini" />
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Highly recommend you to check https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/
An example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can minimize your existing `CSS` and fix little your `HTML` and that's it:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.headings h2, /* since you want headings to be on top style it the same */
.container img { /* instead declare 3 times the same */
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="headings">
  <h2 id="firstheading" class="convertableheading">Mini Convertable</h2>
  <h2 id="secondheading" class="regularheading">Regular Mini</h2>
  <h2 id=thirdheading class=countryheading>Countryman Mini</h2>
</div>

<div class="boxes container"> <!-- you originally declared twice class attribute -->
  <a href="#"><img id="convertiblemini" class="box1" href="#" src="https://vcache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/AHRUND1806DT-S-/800/f" alt="convertible mini cooper"></a>
</div>      
    
<div class="container">
   <a href="#"><img id="countrymanmini" class="box2" class="miniphotobox"  src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staticeu.izmocars.com/toolkit/commonassets/2018/18mini/18minicountrymans5ha2e/18minicountrymans5ha2e_animations/colorpix/fr/640x480/mini_18countrymans5ha2e_thundergreymetallise.jpg"></a>
</div>
  
<div class="container">
  <a href="#"><img id="regularmini" class="box3" class="miniphotobox" src="https://picolio.auto123.com/15photo/mini/2015-mini-cooper-s_1.png"</a>
</div>
```

Hope that helped. Enjoy code!

Answer (score 0):

Set `text-align: center` on the parent element to center the `display: inline-block` elements. See the CSS code for details.

```css
.container {
  position: relative
}
/* Write the common styles in both */
img[class^="box"], /* The [attribute^="value"] selector is used to select elements whose attribute value begins with a specified value. */
h2 {
  width: 30%;
  border: 5px solid black; /* Shortand property */
  display: inline-block; /* Added this because h2 is the block element by default */
  margin: 0 /* Added this because h2 has margin values by default */
}
.box1,
#firstheading {
  float: left /* Aligned the first box and the first head to the left */
}
.box2,
#secondheading {
  float: right /* Aligned the second box and the second head to the left */
}
/* To align the third box and the third head center */
.headings,
.container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="headings">
  <h2 id="firstheading" class="convertableheading">Mini Convertable</h2>
  <h2 id="secondheading" class="regularheading">Regular Mini</h2>
  <h2 id="thirdheading" class="countryheading">Countryman Mini</h2>
</div>

<div class="boxes" class="container"> <!-- Use multiple classes inside the class attribute, separated by whitespace, like this: class="boxes container" -->
  <a href="#"><img id="convertiblemini" class="box1" href="#" src="https://vcache.arnoldclark.com/imageserver/AHRUND1806DT-S-/800/f" alt="convertible mini cooper"></a>
</div>

<div class=container>
  <a href="#"><img id="countrymanmini" class="box2" class="miniphotobox"  src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/staticeu.izmocars.com/toolkit/commonassets/2018/18mini/18minicountrymans5ha2e/18minicountrymans5ha2e_animations/colorpix/fr/640x480/mini_18countrymans5ha2e_thundergreymetallise.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class=container>
  <a href="#"><img id="regularmini" class="box3" class="miniphotobox" src="https://picolio.auto123.com/15photo/mini/2015-mini-cooper-s_1.png"</a>
</div>
```